# How do I make Ubuntu 14.04 recognize my Galaxy S4 as a Microphone via 3.5mm jack/USB?

Tags: sound, android, microphone

Long story short, I'm trying to get some screen recording done and my puppy chewed my microphone rendering it useless.

I've managed to get the Samsung Galaxy S4 i9505 connected as a microphone through both USB and 3.5mm jack on Windows OS however, I am trying to eliminate MS Windows from my PC and I want to get everything I need to be done with Ubuntu.

I've downloaded an app on the phone "Mic to Speaker" and I've connected the phone to the pc via a 3.5mm jack however in the sound app at input, nothing's moving except the "built in" mic which only hears Ubuntu, meaning the clicks, the beeps.

Does anyone know how I can get my Galaxy S4 to become a microphone for my Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select correct  input jack in "input device" tab from "Pulseaudio volume control"
- Type this command in terminal (vlc and vlc-plugin-pulse must be installed ):
  `vlc pulse://`

Vlc will capture pulseaudio recorded signal  and play it to the default pulse output (speaker or headphone).

Comment: ok but this was not the intention, was it?